# CMS that uses s3 for a data store?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, amazon-s3, dam

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions about a DAM (Digital Asset Manager) that uses S3 as a data store? I would like the following features:

1. Asset stored in S3 (or some other cloud storage)
2. The ability to 'tag' the assets
3. Use a CDN (such as Cloudfront or Akamai) to deliver the assets

This can be a solution in any language, but PHP/Ruby on Rails are preferred if it is a web based solution. I understand rolling my own with Paperclip/CarrierWave and acts-as-taggable-on, but I am looking for some input!

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I want to change the requirements. I am not looking for a CMS, I am looking for a DAM (Digital Asset Manager). Thanks!

Comment: Wordpress has a plugin for everything (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tantan-s3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomment Wordpress with an S3 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[Locomotive CMS](http://www.locomotivecms.com/) does use S3. Can be deployed on Heroku with a mongo DB.

edit: [Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com/) too!